# TypeInitializationException for failing tests in TeamCity using VSTest.Console Runner

Tags: .net, teamcity-9.0, vstest

I have got numerous tests failing on 'TypeInitializationException' exceptions. All these tests pass with MSTest In visual-studio and pass in visual studio online. However using teamcity these are failing. 
The runner is VSTest.Console since MSTest Runner doesn't have support for fakes framework.

Teamcity v 9.05
Pluggin: VSTest Support v:32407

Comment: Have you even tried debugging?

Comment: Debugging in VS? they are passing in VS whilst running together or individually, the TypeInitializationException only occurs in the buildLog in teamcity?

Comment: Yeah, so then you attach to the process from VS and debug that way.

Comment: Attach to the process i.e. you mean using profiler? I did debug the particular tests that are failing and they are fine in VS. I used resharper and MSTest to debug they pass in both.
Do you think it is something to do with Ninject? because dependency injection is used throughout the project

Comment: No, I mean with attach to process.  "Debug > attach to process"

Comment: Try running the same activity locally on the command line using the same msbuild version as TeamCity and see what behaviour your get. If it matches TeamCity you at least have a way to test it locally.